# How to zoom the google map in single mouse click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to zoom the google map with desired zoom level by single mouse click.

Comment: What have your tried? The answer yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(this.getZoom() + 1);
    this.setCenter(event.latLng);
});
```

You don't give any indication what you mean by *"desired zoom level"* so I'm assuming you just want to zoom in a bit.

Update: I've also added a line to reset the map's center to wherever you just clicked.

Comment: Its working fine.But how do i auto center the clicked point,when i click 3-4 times that point,that location goes out of screen.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's easy enough to set the centre of the map to where the user clicked.

Comment: I have grids on my map, now i want to click on any grids and that grid complete area should only appear in my screen with getting zoom in to the max level which screen can display.Is it possible in the google map